# Is there a good way to provide ruby pronunciation guides in React Native?

Tags: react-native, internationalization

I've tried searching the docs for any sort of Ruby, furigana, or similar type of pronunciation guide support. I have been unable to find anything. I tried to used nested  components, but have had trouble getting it to work as cleanly as I would like. I am wondering if anyone has found any official support or great way of doing this?

Example of browser support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ruby